# Cannot Access Pipeline Dictionary Entry of View Pipeline in a Component

Tags: intershop

I'm trying to access custom dictionary entry (ManufacturersIterator) from inherited ViewStandardCatalog pipline in overriden component/shopping/FamilyPageCustom template by adding:

```
 <callParameterDefinitions name="ManufacturersIterator" type="java.util.Iterator"/>
```

in interface.pagevariant.content.pagelet2 (also overriden) as described in [Intershop support](https://support.intershop.com/kb/index.php/Display/2T7464) (section 21 Recipe: Access Pipeline Dictionary Entry of View Pipeline in a Component)
 but dictionary entry (ManufacturersIterator) isn't visible in component/shopping/FamilyPageCustom template neither error has occured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far, your approach is correct. The only thing that's missing is the transition point between the pipeline and the actual page (and it's page variant). For that you have to override the call parameter interface 
`interface.page.standard.pagelet2-Interface` residing in cartridge `app_sf_responsive` in file `interface.page.standard.pagelet2`.
Your override must contain the parameter from the original + the new parameter (ManufactursIterator)

**Please note:** Intershop Studio provides you with a wizard to create such an override. File -> New -> Pagelet Model and there you'll see an override existing button. If your cartridge declares correct dependencies, you're able to locate the fore mentioned call parameter interface model.

Comment: Thank for quick response but it didn't worked with only overriding interface.page.standard.pagelet2-Interface, but I added callParameterDefinitions "ManufacturersIterator" in overridden component.shopping.familyPage.pagelet2 and it works.
Maybe it isn't good approach but only one that worked so far.

Comment: So you've overridden the family page component and what else?

Comment: I have override family page component, interface.page.standard.pagelet2-Interface as you suggested and ViewStandardCatalog pipeline, all from app_sf_responsive.